# How to remove the association after deleting a model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple has_many/belongs_to association between 2 of my models.
My problem is that when I delete an object that I no longer want (from the parent model), the foreign key within the child model's object remains. For example:

**Forest**

`has_many :trees, :inverse_of => :forest`

**Tree**

`belongs_to :forest`

When I delete a `Forest` object, all the associated `Tree` objects still contain a value for `forest_id`, which results in errors on the frontend. Is there some sort of hook like `before_destroy` that I can use? Though I'm thinking there's probably a very simple solution to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you want the `:dependent` option.

```
has_many :trees, :inverse_of => :forest, :dependent => :nullify
```

This will set the foreign keys to `nil` when the associated model is destroyed. You could also use `:dependent => :destroy` to destroy the model.

[The documentation here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Dependent+associations) might help.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, unfortunately it doesn't work? The foreign key remains

Comment: you could try using `:dependent => :restrict`, which will throw an exception if rails thinks a foreign key exists... just to verify that the dependent option is being set.

Comment: Ahhh it works - my bad, I put the `:dependent` option on the wrong model. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have add the :dependent option with the association like

has_many :trees, :dependent => :destroy

It will delete all trees of a particular Forest object.

Comment: I'd rather just orphan the trees rather than destroy them. Save the trees!! ;)